# Rails 5.2.3 missing required keys: [:id] in new.html.erb form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

I have this controller:

```
class MynewsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        render plain: params[:mynew].inspect
    end
end
```

this row in routes.rb:

```
 resources :mynews
```

and this new.html.erb file:

```
<h1>New Mynews</h1>

<%= form_with scope: :mynew, local: true do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :title %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :title %>
    </p>
   
    <p>
      <%= form.label :body %><br>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </p>
   
    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

It display the form and when i hit submit it displays the expected `No route matches [POST] "/mynews/new"`  error

The problem is when i add the url parameter in the form_with row:

```
<%= form_with scope: :mynew, url: mynews_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

http://localhost:3000/mynews/new doesn't display the form and gives

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"mynews"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

error.

I can't find what is the problem. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `form_with scope:` try this instead.

In your controller's `new` action you need to create a new unsaved record. I have no idea what your model is called, so I'm guessing based on your controller name:

```
def new
  @mynew = Mynew.new
end
```

Next, in your view, do the form like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @mynew, local: true do |form| %>
```

And it'll handle the paths etc for you.

However, I suspect your model probably isn't called `Mynew`, in which case you'd have to specify the url.

Assuming your model is actually called something like `Article`, I'd advise you to also name your controller `ArticlesController`. If you want the actual URL to be different you can configure that in your `routes` file ... but creating/updating/deleting an `Article` should be handled by the `ArticlesController`, regardless of what URL the users see.